# How does Twitter Bootstrap manage <p> elements in <span>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I think I might be asking a stupid question here, but I've just started implementing twitter bootstrap in a new project of mine which requires a responsive layout. I am using the 'span' methodology of putting all my content in a span grid.

I was putting some text content in a span, when I got a validation warning. Paragraph element can't be nested in span.

How are we supposed to put in text content in twitter bootstrap if not in paragraph elements?

Any insights folks?

Answer (score 7):

I think you might be mixing up the concepts of HTML `<span>` elements and Bootstrap's grid classes `.span4`, `.span8`, ... . HTML paragraphs (`<p></p>`) are *block elements* and must not be placed inside *inline elements* like `<span></span>`. Hence the validation warning is thrown. Bootstrap's span-classes are to be used in combination with `<div>` elements. It's fine to place paragraphs in there:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">...</div>
  <div class="span8">...</div>
</div>
```

Have a look at the examples at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: Just to add to this answer, the `span` element is meant to be used inline with other text, not to group text elements together.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a paragraph in bootstrap just put it in a div with a the span class you need. For example if you want the paragraph to expand to the 4 columns of the 12 column grid you would put it like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span4">
       <p>Some text...</p>
   </div>
</div>
```